# How to change type of foreign key in Laravel migration from int to uuid

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I´ve **two tables** (products, brands) with the following structure:

```
#products
id<pk,int> | brand_id<fk, int> | title<string>

#brands
id<pk,int> | title<string>
```

Now my challenge is that I have to change the **primary keys from int to UUID** via migrations. As brand_id in #products is a foreign key there is also an index for the key that has to be deleted/recreated to avoid an error to due incompatible types.

**Here´s how my migration file looks like at the moment:**

```
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            Schema::withoutForeignKeyConstraints(function () use ($table) {
                $table->dropForeignIdFor(Brand::class);
                $table->char('brand_id', 36)->change();
            });
        });
}
```

However, I still get the **following exception** and I´ve no idea why:

```
General error: 3780 Referencing column 'brand_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'products_brand_id_foreign' are incompatible.
```

Do you know what I´m doing wrong?